# strtok and int vs char in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, strtok

I am learning how to delimate char arrays and I need to do an operation where I split a number and string into different variables and print them out. I believe I am close but when printing out what should be my number I get crazy numbers. Is this the address to the int? Any advice is greatly appreciated! My code and input/output:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        setbuf(stdout, NULL);
        char name[10];
        printf("Enter in this format, integer:name\n");
        fgets(name, 10, stdin);                            //my input was 2:brandon
        char *n = strtok(name, ":");
        int num = (int)n;
        char * order = strtok(NULL, ":");
        printf("%d,%s", num,order);                        //my output was 7846332,brandon
        return (0);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
int num = (int)n;
```

> Is this the address to the int?

No, it is an address of the character buffer at the position where the character representation of your integer is stored, re-interpreted as an `int` (i.e. it may be a truncated address, making it pretty much a meaningless number).

You can convert it to int either by parsing the value, or using `atoi`:

```
int num = atoi(n);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ljOq1B)

Comment: In general `strtol()` is a better choice than `atoi()` because strtol is more flexible and atoi is lame about error reporting.

Comment: @John Hascall Agree `strtol()` is better than `atoi()` because of potential for good error handling.  But that can involve something like `errno = 0; char *endptr; long tmp = strtol(n, &endptr, 10); if (endptr == n) Handle_NoConversion(); if (errno || tmp < INT_MIN || tmp > INT_MAX) Handle_Overflow(); n = (int) tmp;`

Answer (score 4):

If you give e.g. `"123:foobar"` as input, the pointer `n` points to the *string* `"123"`. When you cast the pointer to an integer, the value of the integer is the value of the variable `n` which is the address of where in memory the string returned by `strtok` is located.

If you want to convert a string containing a number to an actual number, you should use e.g. the [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function:

```
int num = strtol(n, NULL, 10);
```